# Failed to add node on Chained List

Tags: c, list, pointers

I wanted to create a chained list, initialize it and add a new node at the beginning.
But i have this problem :

//**//
error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union
//**//

```
t_bool list_add_elem_at_front(t_list *front_ptr, double elem)
{
  if (front_ptr == NULL)
    {
      front_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*front_ptr));

      front_ptr->value = elem;
      front_ptr->next = NULL;
    }
  printf("%f\n", front_ptr->value);
  return (TRUE);
}
```

I'm sure the struct is malloc but I really don't get why it doesn't find "value" and the "*next" on the structure

```
int main(void)
 {
  int i = 2.1;

  t_list list_head = NULL;
  list_add_elem_at_front(&list_head, i);
 }
```

**And the header file**

```
typedef struct  s_node
{
    double          value;
    struct s_node   *next;
}               t_node;

typedef t_node   *t_list;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
t_bool list_add_elem_at_front(t_list *front_ptr, double elem)
{
  if (*front_ptr == NULL)
    {
      *front_ptr = malloc(sizeof(**front_ptr));

      (*front_ptr)->value = elem;
      (*front_ptr)->next = NULL;
    }
  printf("%f\n", (*front_ptr)->value);
  return (TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Thx dude it's actually working. Can i have some explications please ?

Comment: You need to do `malloc(sizeof(**front_ptr))` for this solution.

Comment: @Laykker In terms of the code of your, `front_ptr` is pointer `to list_head`. Requires dereference to the actual.

Comment: and `int i = 2.1;` --> `double i = 2.1;`

Comment: Really helpful, so much love for you guy !

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
t_bool list_add_elem_at_front(t_list *front_ptr, double elem)
```

You have too many pointers in the argument:

```
t_list *front_ptr
```

when you combine that with:

```
typedef t_node   *t_list;
```

result in a `t_node**`

Rather than remove the `*` in the argument, I would just use `t_node *` everywhere

Comment: I know, but i wanted to do this on this way

Comment: @Laykker - I see you wanted to use the `typedef` -- Doing a dereference on the `t_list *` would work, but your code would be clearer (and possibly your error messages) if you didn't use pointer `typedef`s in this way

Answer (score 0):

And additionally the problem is in the argument of sizeof that should be t_node

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @(Glen Teitelbaum) Yes, but is not the only problem

Comment: Just noting that issue won't cause: `//// error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union ////`

Comment: @(Glen Teitelbaum) you are right, but in C issues doesn't comes never alone :-)

Comment: It might be clearer to state, "and additionally, the problem is in the argument..."  and then show the correct code.  BTW, can I have my **'n'** back?

Comment: @(Glenn Teitelbaum) of course. BTW thank you for the suggestion, I will edit the answer in a while